# adding filter to bluetooth discovery

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I want to just discover peripheral devices when i start my Bluetooth Device discovery, my app must not discover/show other devices. is this any how possible?

this is how i am searching for devices

```
  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.DEVICE_SELECTED");
  registerReceiver(mBtPickReceiver,filter);

  startActivity(new Intent("android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.LAUNCH")
 .putExtra("android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.EXTRA_NEED_AUTH",false));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reduce (filter) the number of searched devices as per your requirements, check the **Class Type** of your desired bluetooth device. Once you know the type , you may filter the searched bluetooth devices based on their class type. For example:

```
BluetoothDevice btd = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

if(btd.getBluetoothClass().getDeviceClass() == BluetoothClass.Device.bla_bla_bla)
{
   //do whatever you want with the filtered device
}
```

Comment: my point is when i click my search devices button it should only search for peripheral devices, nothing else. Is this possible?

Comment: and what do you exactly mean by peripheral devices? each and every bluetooth device is categorized within a long list of pre-defined class types. Do you know what class type your peripheral device(s) belong to?

Comment: let say i know the class no. ,and i just want devices having this class no. to be shown.
also i have edited my question to show exactly how i am searching for devices.

Comment: Let Bluetooth adapter search for anything it encounters, and what you can do is to qualify/mark only those devices which fulfill your class type and show them in your search-result.

Comment: i am not writing the code for searching and displaying, i m just using the inbuilt BluetoothdevicePicker which uses the inbuilt bluetooth settings to search and display all the bluetooth devices near by. i want to put a filter.  the thing which you are talking about will definitely work but only when i am the one displaying the devices..

Comment: I'm not sure if you have enough options available when it comes to use device picker, but anyhow you may try [android.bluetooth.devicepicker.extra.FILTER_TYPE](http://code.google.com/p/backport-android-bluetooth/source/browse/trunk/backport-android-bluetooth201/eclair/BluetoothDevicePicker.java?r=47) which differentiates between 3 types of devices (all/audio/transfer). Besides, implementing your own device picker together with my suggestions would be the best option to go with